Reading IP addresses from a pcap file with gopacket
Solved: it was a linux cooked file. so had to modify the packet like this:
packetByte := packet.Data()
packet = gopacket.NewPacket(packetByte[20:], layers.LayerTypeIPv4, gopacket.Default)

I have a pcap file, and when i look at it on wireshark, I see two adresses, like 100.2.1.1 and 100.2.1.10 in whole file. So this is just a communication between these two network elements. But when I try to read these adresses using gopacket, I get different addresses. Couldn't figure this problem for days so now reaching out.
